# json.dump({...}, fp) writes to fp with str chunks instead of desired unicode chunks in Python 2. Can I force it use unicode?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I'm trying to write something that will work in Python 3 and 2. Currently it works in 3, but in 2 the `json` module is calling write with a `str` object instead of a `unicode` object.

In the [`dump`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dump) method it warns:

> If ensure_ascii is true (the default), all non-ASCII characters in the output are escaped with \uXXXX sequences, and the result is a str instance consisting of ASCII characters only. If ensure_ascii is false, some chunks written to fp may be unicode instances. This usually happens because the input contains unicode strings or the encoding parameter is used. Unless fp.write() explicitly understands unicode (as in codecs.getwriter()) this is likely to cause an error.

I actually would like to force it to always prepare its chunks as unicode.

In the [`JSONEncoder`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder) method it has an option that seems to promise that:

> If encoding is not None, then all input strings will be transformed into unicode using that encoding prior to JSON-encoding. The default is UTF-8.

but `dump`'s `encoding` is defaulted to `'utf-8'` and does not exhibit this promised behavior.

My code is dumping json to a `TextIOWrapper` buffering `BytesIO` because I want to give a bytes file-like-object to `requests` as it says that it may get an inaccurate content-length with a plain text string.

```py
with io.BytesIO() as request, \
        io.TextIOWrapper(request, encoding='utf-8') as req_str:
    json.dump({
        'name': 'try_genie', 'theres': 'more omitted'},
    }, req_str)
    req_str.seek(0)
    request.seek(0)
    response = requests.post(
        url=self.host + self.endpoint,
        files=(
            ('request', (None, request, self.request_content_type)),
            ('attachment', ('query.hql',
                            'select "토탈", count(1) from products;'
                            .encode(encoding='utf-8'),
                            self.request_content_type)),
        ),
    )
```

The exception message is:

```
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 190, in dump
    fp.write(chunk)
TypeError: write() argument 1 must be unicode, not str
```

Comment: Why don't you want to do a full `json.dumps` (into a string, not a file-like object) if you're holding the whole result in memory anyway?

Comment: @MikhailBurshteyn I did end up thinking along those same lines… so the request package said for multipart to have the correct content-lenght it should be given bytes in preference to str or unicode. So I used `dumps().encode('utf-8')` which seems to work fine in both and is probably doing about the same thing in memory.

Comment: I thought maybe importing unicode literals from `__future__` and using them in the keys to the json dict might help, but it didn't alter the behavior. The `dumps().encode('utf-8')` route still makes best sense.

Answer (score 1):

In python2, normal string are byte strings, not unicode strings. That means that under normal circumstances, `json.dump` will try to write a byte string, which is not accepted in an `io.TextIOWrapper`. In Python 2 you should only use bytes oriented file objects with `json`, because even if the documentation pretends that some chunks could be unicode data, I could never have the first chunk be anything else than a byte string.

So if you need a file like object, stick to an `io.BytesIO`:

```
with io.BytesIO() as request:
    json.dump({
        'name': 'try_genie', 'theres': 'more omitted'},
    }, request)
    request.seek(0)
    response = requests.post(
        url=self.host + self.endpoint,
        files=(
            ('request', (None, request, self.request_content_type)),
            ...
```

`request`being a bytes file object, there will be no further convertion, and the character count will be accurate.

But I must say that this is one of the points where I cannot write code for both Python 2 and Python 3. So my advice if to use something like:

```
with io.BytesIO() as request:
  if sys.version_info.major == 2:
    json.dump({                   # Python 2: write directly to request
        'name': 'try_genie', 'theres': 'more omitted'},
    }, request)
  else:                           # Python 3: write to a TestIOWrapper wrapping request
    with io.TextIOWrapper(request, encoding='utf-8') as req_str:
        json.dump({'name': 'try_genie', 'theres': 'more omitted'},
                  req_str)
        req_str.seek(0)
  request.seek(0)
  ...
```